# Как получить Content-Disposition Header в Retrofit 2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rxjava, okhttp

Загружаю файл с сервера с помощью Retrofit 2, возник вопрос, как можно с Headers с Content-Disposition получить название файла?

```
@GET("file/{msg}")
    Observable<ResponseBody> getFile(@Path("msg") String msg);
```

Метод для загрузки файла:

```
 public static void receiveFileServer(String msg) {
        Subscription subscription = BaseApi.getInstance().service.getFile(msg)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(file -> {
                    writeResponseBodyToDisk(file);
                }, throwable -> {
                    Log.e("File from server error", String.valueOf(throwable));
                });
        addSubscription(subscription);
    }

 public static void addSubscription(Subscription subscription) {
        compositeSubscription.add(subscription);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@GET("file/{msg}")
Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> getFile(@Path("msg") String msg);
```

--

```
public static void receiveFileServer(String msg) {
        Subscription subscription = BaseApi.getInstance().service.getFile(msg)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(response -> {
                    String contentDisposition= response.headers().get("Content-Disposition");
                    writeResponseBodyToDisk(response.body());
                }, throwable -> {
                    Log.e("File from server error", String.valueOf(throwable));
                });
        addSubscription(subscription);
}

public static void addSubscription(Subscription subscription) {
        compositeSubscription.add(subscription);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я убрала `RxJava`, и переписала код, получила нужный `Header` с помощью `response.headers().get("Content-Disposition")`.

Измененный код:

@GET("file/{msg}")
    Call  getFile(@Path("msg") String msg);

метод для загрузки файла:

```
public static void receiveFile(String msg, File fileReceived, String senderJid) {
        Call<ResponseBody> call = BaseApi.getInstance().service.getFile(msg);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>(){

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                String contentDisposition= response.headers().get("Content-Disposition");
                writeResponseBodyToDisk(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Если кто-то знает, как получить данный Header используя `RxJava` буду признательна ответу.